# Multi-tenant resolve tenant context in admin site

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application in dot net core 2.1. I have used the identity framework for user management. I have two web projects and two data context for tenant and system.

```
SystemDb (SystemDbContext)- central database

TenantDb (TenantDbContext)- tenant (this has TenantId filter)
```

When I create a tenant from system portal, I want to create a default admin user in tenant database. I want to know what is the best way to resolve the tenant data context. Tenant Entity has the connection to the database.

```
public class TenantManagementService: ITenantManagementService
{
    private readonly ISystemDbContext _systemDbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<SystemUser> _userManager;

    public InsertTenantDetailsCommandHandler(ISystemDbContext systemDbContext, UserManager<SystemUser> userManager)
    {
        _systemDbContext = systemDbContext;
    }

    public async Task CreateTenant(Tenant tenant)
    {
        await _systemDbContext.Tenants.AddAsync(tenant);
        await _systemDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // I need to create default user in tenantDbContext
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could place the tenant context in a different project by itself and reference the resulting dll file in the System project.